# Como somar o resultado que esta dentro da função Split em python?

Tags: python

Valor de entrada: `6+5`

Exemplo: dentro da variavel `data` estão os numeros `['6', '5']`,

```
print (data).split('+')
```

como faço para printar a soma desses valores?

Answer (score 1):

Use o [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
data = ['6', '5'] 

print (sum(int(numero) for numero in data if numero.isdigit())) # 11
```

Answer (score 0):

> Considerando que você sempre receberá ou caracteres numéricos ou
>   operações matemáticas.

Primeiramente você separará os dados da string que chega para você:

```
>>> string = "6+5".split("+")
>>> string
['6','5']
```

Depois tem que transformá-los em números tratáveis por funções do python, para isso use o `int`ou o `float`. Vou usar a função `map` para efetuar uma operação para cada elemento da lista.

```
>>> operadores = list( map(float,string) )
>>> operadores
[6.0 , 5.0]
>>> soma = sum(operadores)
11.0
```

Ou utilizando menos variáveis:

```
soma = sum ( list ( map ( float,data ) ) )
```